# Issue with onClickListener for Button in Fragment

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a button in a fragment class that I'd like to have trigger a method in the parent activity. I've implemented an interface for this.

My issue is that the View.onClickListener is giving me the following error:

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from onClickListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'onClickListener'

Which is odd, because I'm implementing onClick(View).

Here is the code in my Fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(com.zlaporta.chessgame.R.layout.gamedescfragment, container, false);
        final Button make_move = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.make_move);
        make_move.setOnClickListener(new ***View.OnClickListener()*** {
            public void OnClick(View v) {
                makeMoveCallback.makeMoveMethod();
            }
        });
```

The stars indicate the portion of the code that Android Studio doesn't like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it using Anonymous inner class in an object:

```
//declaring OnClickListener as an object
private OnClickListener btnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

//passing listener object to button
make_move.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: This works, but why?? what was wrong with my more traditional implementation?

Comment: Because OnClickListener is an interface and by using new OnClickListener() as parameter for make_move.setOnClickListener it is actually creating an Anonymous Inner Class which implements OnClickListener. And the method onClick must need to be declared since its an abstract method inside that interface class :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a typo: Replace the method name

```
OnClick
```

with

```
onClick
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try passing the OnClickListener from a method

e.g.,

```
private View.OnClickListener getButtonOnClickListener() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // this is the code
        }
    };
}
```

and then using `make_move.setOnClickListener(getButtonOnClickListener());`

Answer (score 1):

This is best way to using click event for button. using onClick listener implementing. use below code.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
Button mButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null);
    mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == mButton) {
        // Do something on click button
    }

}
}
```

If using every click event separately it take more space. its better to use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Override` above `onClick` method

Comment: That doesn't work. 'Method does not Override method from it's superclass'

Comment: Is that View.OnClickListener from Android or has been changed ? Basically the error says that you are not implementing a method in interface OnClickListener. But you already or supposedly have which is public void onClick(View v). If you use IDE like Android Stuido maybe you should delete it, start over, and let the IDE generate the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use below method of button click Listener in **OnActivityCreated()** methos of **Fragment**.

> ```
> make_move.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>           @Override
>           public void onClick(View view) {
>
>                   makeMoveCallback.makeMoveMethod();
>
>           }
> });
> ```