# Using textview to switch between fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I trying to switch fragment to activity using textview. Which mean when I pressed on the textview eg start it will bring me to another activity. I implement the code below but is not working. 
FragmentThree.java

```
public class FragmentThree extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three_layout,container,false);

    }

    public void Onclick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.start:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }


}//end of fragment
```

fragment 3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E1F5FE" >
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="189dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Added more details. When I implements View.OnClickListener I got the following error Class 'FragmentThree' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'

Comment: you should write a method `click()` in your activity containing this fragment

Comment: @Logic can you elaborate more?

Comment: setonclicklistner for textview like `textview.setOnclickListner(this);` in onCreateView, *check out the answer i have posted*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three_layout,container,false);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
  tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);

        }
    }); return view;
    }
```

Comment: it said missing return statement

Answer (score 2):

You specifiy in your layout that the method name for onClick is "click"
So your code should be

```
public void click(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.start:
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
  }
}
```

additionally set tag `android:clickable="true"`to your TextView

Comment: it said Method 'click(android.view.View)' is never used

Comment: and do I need to include implement onClicklister after the fragments?

Comment: Did you try it in the proposed way? It should be working, you can ignore the warning. If you specify an onClick attribute in your layout, you don't need to set an onClickListener, but please add clickable attribute and set it to true, since you have a text view and not a Button.

Comment: Hi I tried @boyapati's answer. It worked. Thanks for your helped too.

Answer (score 1):

when you write `android:onClick="click"` it searches for a method `click()` in your `Activity`
So in your `Activity` give a method like

```
public void click(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

What you have assumed wrong here is, the click on the textview will be moving to onClickListener which. It doesn't work in that way.
`android:onClick="click"` searched for a method **click** in your `Activity`

Comment: erm ok then? how do I assign my textview? Sorry I added additional details. Edited it. Do I need to implements Onclicklistener?

Comment: it saying click is never use

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Hi @boyapati answer solved my problem. Both your answers are quite similar. But I not able to tick both. Just want to say thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
  tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //DO YOUR THING HERE

        }
    });
```

Comment: hi I pasted it on the onCreateview and it said Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' and also Method does not override method from its superclass

Answer (score 0):

write below code in FragmentThree class below onCreateView method and remove click listener

```
public void click(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it working fine

```
 Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        click(v);
    }
});



public void click(View v) {
    // does something 
}

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="189dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three_layout,container,false);
TextView tv=(TextView)v.findviewByid(R.id.text1);
tv.setonClicklistner(getActivity());
    return v;

}
```

**Reason**  : click event is not firing in your case is this only to set click event on any widgt we have to set click listner on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
  tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi I placed your code after this line: return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three_layout,container,false);
But I getting this error Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'

Comment: Please see i added another answer

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 different ways of achieving a `Click` - you can either add

```
android:onClick="tvClick"
```

attribute to your `TextView` in your `xml` - then you have to add this method named `tvClick()`to your `Activity`

```
public void tvClick(){
    //...
}
```

Or you can `implement View.OnClickListener`, **overwrite** the `onClick()` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.start:
           // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You missed setOnClickListener(getActivity());
    Use this to perform onClick()

    Use this code:
      public void click(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.start:
      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
      }
```

}

Comment: where do I place this setOnClickListener(getActivity());?

Comment: and erm do I need to do this public class FragmentThree extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener?

Comment: because I getting error Class 'FragmentThree' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640674/issue-with-onclicklistener-for-button-in-fragment

Comment: Please help. I don't quite understand where to place the code